# Discord.py voting command not responding

Tags: discord, discord.py

I made this command called `p!poll [message]` where I want my bot to send an embed with [message] for the description and react with the emojis  and . The command, however, isn't responding and I don't understand why.

```py
@client.command
async def poll(ctx, *, message):
    embedVar = discord.Embed(title='Poll', description=f'{message}')
    msg = await ctx.channel.send(embed=embedVar)
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
```

Comment: Did you try adding in a `print(message)`, or some alternate logging, as the first line of your `poll` function to ensure that it is indeed being called? It looks like the library uses code injection/syntactic sugar so are you calling some kind of main loop?

Comment: Ok im gonna try that
I didnt get any response I dont think it notices the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command is forgetting to call the command, which is the double parenthesis, ()

Simply can be fixed by adding: `client.command()` to the top where it previously says without the parenthesis

It's better to include "None" in your message decorator, as it allows members to know they must pass a message through, otherwise it would not run the command.

I choose to optionally add some more functionality to your command, (only if you wish for use) and the option of sending it to a different channel, but I have tried this and should work. Hope this helps, change it to whatever you need.

```
@client.command()
async def poll(ctx, *, message=None):

        if message == None:
                await ctx.send(f'Cannot create a poll with no message!')
                return

        questions = [
            f"Which channel should your poll be sent to?"
        ]
        answers = []

        def check(m):
                return m.author == ctx.author and m.channel == ctx.channel

        for i in questions:
                await ctx.send(i)

                try:

                      msg = await client.wait_for('message', timeout=30.0, check=check)
                
                except asyncio.TimeoutError:
                        await ctx.send("Setup timed out, please be quicker next time!")
                        return
                else:
                        answers.append(msg.content)

        try:
                c_id = int(answers[0][2:-1])
        except:
                await ctx.send(
                    f"You didn't mention a channel properly, please format like {ctx.channel.mention} next time."
                )
                return

        channel = client.get_channel(c_id)


        embed = discord.Embed(title="Poll", description='{message}', colour=discord.Color.black())
        message = await channel.send(embed=embed )

        await message.add_reaction('')
        await message.add_reaction('')
```

Comment: o ya it says that `asyncio.TimeoutError` is not defined

Comment: have you imported asyncio? -- import asyncio

Comment: oh I didnt sorry

Comment: I DONT WANT TO BE ANNOYING but its like before nothings happening

Comment: I've tested both commands myself, it could just be a problem with how you are running your bot. But in your question the only part wrong is the missing parenthesis () 
Other than that, the command runs properly

Comment: wait what's the command? p!poll [message] ?